Include an RGBD cam to my robot with humble and gz sim harmonic
I am trying to add an RGBD camera to my robot model. My setup is : ROS2 humble with gz harmonic.
Here what I have done so far to set up my simulation:

I created a robot.urdf.xacro file
I created a rgbd_camera.xacro where I attempt to configure a sensor of type RGBD
I created a launch.py using ros_gz_bridge to connect my gazebo sensors and plugins to ROS

However, at the moment, nothing is being published on the camera topics ...
Could someone help me by explaining me how the rgbd_camera.xacro should be structured and  how to properly configure the sensor ? Also, if needed, what is the name of the plugin I should use for this application ?
Thank you in advance!! :)

Could you share your current xacro's, the bridge and the part of the launch file where the bridge is set up?
